# How to best resume training of Pytorch Lightning model logging to MLFlow

Tags: pytorch, mlflow, pytorch-lightning

I'm using Pytorch Lightning and MLFlow to track model training. In my use-case, I often create a model and train it for a while, then stop the process, adjust learning rate, load the best model from the previous run and continue training. What I want is to have everything in the same MLFlow run, so that I can see the progress graphs and have everything there neatly.

The following skeleton is the code I'm using, it sort of works and I can see that MLFlow kind of knows what I'm doing: I can see the training curves fine when having timestamps in the x axis, and the artifacts are saved in different folders (X-1, X-2, X-3, etc.). However it seems that when I log metrics they don't have an associated `step` value or something like that, so they start at 0 and overlap.

I would like to refine my code to be able to keep track of a global step.

```
import lightning as L
from lightning.pytorch.loggers import MLFlowLogger


class MyLightningModel(L.LightningModule):
    [...]
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        [...]
        if (batch_idx + 1) % self.log_every_n_steps == 0:
            self.log(
                "lr", self.trainer.optimizers[0].param_groups[0]["lr"], sync_dist=True
            )
            self.log("avg_train_loss", avg_loss, prog_bar=True, sync_dist=True)
            self.logger.experiment.log_artifact(
                self.logger.run_id, "last_model.pth", "model"
            )

        return loss


existing_run_id = "RUN_ID"
experiment_name = "EXP_NAME"
experiment_id = "EXP_ID"

checkpoint_path = (
    f"mlruns/{experiment_id}/{existing_run_id}/artifacts/best_model.pth"
)

model = MyLightningModel.load_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_path)

mlf_logger = MLFlowLogger(
    experiment_name=experiment_name, run_id=existing_run_id, log_model="all"
)

trainer = L.Trainer(
    [...]
    logger=mlf_logger,
)

trainer.fit(
    model,
    [...]
)
```

Any ideas welcome!